# ASP MVC 3, how to set model properties in controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I've got a view with a submit formular (Html.BeginForm()), and want to set some model properties *in the controller*, returning the view, hoping to see this properties in the view.

Here is my pattern on the standard MVC 3 logon formular.

**Precision**: *I really want to set these properties within the POST treatment, not in a GET.*

Could you please explain why my properties set in the controller are never displayed on the view?

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        model.RememberMe = true;
        model.UserName = "foobar";

        return View(model);
    }
```

With a view like the standard LogOn.cshtml:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        <div>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Account Information</legend>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                </div>

                <p>
                    <input type="submit" value="Log On" />
                </p>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    }
```

Comment: could u tell, on view its displaying  `@Model.UserName` or not??

Comment: Are you sure your LogOn action is being called?  When the viw first opens, it won't hit the [HttpPost] version of the action.

Comment: @BenFinkel: yes this is what i was thinking..

Comment: On your initial load it will respond to an HTTP GET, not a POST.  Your code is only going to get hit when it posts (which will be fine if there is an error and you want to redisplay the view).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use in HttpPost Action than you have to do following way.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        ModelState.Remove("RememberMe");
        ModelState.Remove("UserName");
        model.RememberMe = true;
        model.UserName = "foobar";
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks dotnetstep, exactly what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i understand ur problem : add this action to ur controller

```
   /*no http post*/
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        model = model ?? new LogOnModel();
        model.RememberMe = true;
        model.UserName = "foobar";

        return View(model);
    }
```

### As per ur comment

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        ModelState.Clear();
        model.RememberMe = true;
        model.UserName = "foobar";

        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: I may not have been clear enough in my question: I want to fill this properties _within_ the post, so as to update the view

Comment: although u have  accepted some other answer but as per ur comment i have updated my answer. There is always a scope for improvement.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing what the `[HttpPost]` flag is doing. This attribute identifies the action as the one to be used when a request is sent to the server as a POST. When you are first looking at the page, the standard request by the browser is a GET. Your POST action should be the one that checks the submitted form's credentials.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    model.RememberMe = true;
    model.UserName = "foobar";

    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        //Verify input here
    }
```

Comment: I may not have been clear enough in my question: I want to fill this properties within the post, so as to update the view